# How do I set up a WKExtendedRuntimeSession for a standalone watchOS app on Xcode 14?

Tags: xcode, watchos

watchOS noob here...

I created a standalone watchOS app in Xcode 14.2 and it has no "Extension" target, which I think is the expected behavior. But I would like to use a WKExtendedRuntimeSession and the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/using_extended_runtime_sessions) says to "enable your WatchKit extension’s Background Modes capability and select your app’s session type".

How am I supposed to do this if I don't have an extension?

Answer (score 0):

`ExtendedRuntimeSessions` are a different concept from WatchKit Extensions. You can specify the App's session type by

1. Going to "Signing & Capabilities" for the target in Xcode,
2. Tapping "+" to add the background capability and,
3. Selecting the Session type (eg Self Care, Smart Alarm)

This does not require creating a WidgetKit extension.